# Why am I getting a 429 error when I'm way below 15,000 requests?

Tags: api, limit, rate

I'm testing on my local and finding the rate limit is maxing out at around maybe 100 requests or so. I read in the api docs that the limit is 15,000 requests per 24 hours. Any insight why I'm getting a 429 error when I'm way below the 15,000 request mark?
Cheers

Comment: Why not ask whoever maintains that API? There might be some APIs that count requests to a collection different than requests to a single item

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.